# Laravel leftJoin two tables and where condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have one Laravel issue. I need to translate this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `translations` t 
    LEFT JOIN shortcuts s ON t.bonusid = s.bonusid 
    WHERE t.lang = s.lang
```

to Laravel syntax. Unfortunately this does not work for me:

```
DB::connection('mysql_old')->table('translations as t')
    ->leftJoin('shortcuts as s', 't.bonusid', '=', 's.bonusid')
    ->where('t.lang', '=', 's.lang')->get();
```

Comment: _Does not work_ Hmmmm thats a really helpful description. Would you like to expand a little?

Comment: the syntax where('t.lang', '=', 's.lang') is not right. but i dont know how is the correct syntax for where with two different tables ?

Comment: Is it `->whereColumn('t.lang', 's.lang')`

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly !

Comment: Just a comment:  the condition in the WHERE clause (requiring a non-NULL value of s.lang in order for the condition to return TRUE) effectively negates the "outerness" of the LEFT JOIN. If you really want an outer join, the condition in the WHERE clause needs to be moved to the ON clause.Otherwise, the LEFT keyword is superfluous.

Comment: Vince: That took me 5 minutes in the manual.